# Разработка DAPP на блокчейне Ethereum

Tags: ethereum

Начал разбираться как разрабатывать смарт-контракты на блокчейне Ethereum и как писать web-скрипт для взаимодействия с смарт контрактом (покупка, продажа, статистика ...) И пришел к выводу, что за чем делать. Хотел узнать правильно ли я все понял.

1. Пишем контракт на http://remix.ethereum.org, проверяем все ли функции работают правильно.
2. Поднимаем `TRUFFLE+GANACHE` для тестирования контракта на собственном приватном блокчейне.
3. Пишем простенький `front-end` для взаимодействия с контрактом, будем все делать через `Metamask`.
4. Заливаем все в тестовую сеть `Ropsten Ethereum` и тестируем все там.
5. После успешного тестирования в тестовой сети, заливаем все в главный блокчейн кефира.

Все ли я правильно понял, и правильные ли шаги предпринял?

Comment: Ты забыл деплой

Answer (score 1):

редактирование truffle.js . Деплой .И ганаче в принципе не нужен локаль можно локальные тесты провести через truffle develop, запустится тот же testrpc только без GUI.
Truffle init 
Truffle develop
deploy 
Migret 
Test